# Joining two tables (with a many to one relationship) taking long

Tags: sql, performance, join, common-table-expression

I have two tables, table 1 has a column X, table 2 has a column that relates to column X.

In Table 1 the entries of column X are repeated (i.e entries can be {1,1,2,3,5,4,4,4,9})

In Table 2 the entries that column X are not repeated but all the distinct entries in table 1 appear

So there is one to many relationship

Now I want to join the two tables(as seen below in the code) and the performance is extremely slow!

Any ideas?

```
> CTE_DE_Normalised AS
        (
            SELECT  *

            FROM    Table1 a

            JOIN    Table2 b
            ON  a.Id = b.Table1Id
        )
```

Comment: Why do you need a CTE rather than a normal join?

Comment: If the above is slow, make sure you have indexes on your Table1.id field and Table2.TableId field.

Comment: What database are you using?  How large are the tables?  How many times have you run the timings?  Often, the first time you run a query, it runs slowly because the data fills internal caches.

Comment: What does the rest of your query look like?  Do you have a foreign key defined, and is it trusted?  can you post the definition script?